# Excel pivot add field base on two other calculated fields

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table, powerpivot

I added two columns to my pivot which calculates sums of hours like this :
[image]

I would like to add another column which is based on those two new columns, that calculates their quotient 'Sum of Avail Hrs'/'Sum of Eff Hrs' but couldn't find how to do it.

[image]

Please help! 
Thank you

(There is a question asked a bit similar to my issue but there is no answer to it.)

Comment: How is `Avail Hrs` calculated and how is `Eff Hrs` calculated? Assuming that you'll tell me that `Avail Hrs` is calculated as `={Formula1}` and `Eff Hrs` is calculated as `={Formula2}` the answer you are looking for is `={Formula1}/{Formula2}`.

Comment: @Ralph It looks like OP is using implicit measures and will need to create an explicit measure to do what they want.

Comment: @AlexisOlson please elaborate. I don't understand.

Comment: @Ralph OP likely didn't write any formulas for `Sum of Avail Hrs` and `Sum of Eff Hrs`, but just put the `Avail Hrs` and `Eff Hrs` fields in the Values box and Excel automatically chose to aggregate them using a sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a calculated field to do this.

[image: Calculated Field]

In that pop-up box, you can create the formula you want.

[image: Quotient]

Then add it to your pivot table.

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out before, there is a "trick" behind it that you didn't mention : there is no need to calculate sum of avail hrs or sums of eff hrs manually, Excel understand that the field  'Avail hrs'/'Eff Hrs' means actually 'Sum of Avail hrs'/Sum of 'Eff Hrs' in the pivot.